ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10054 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency
ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=10054 Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
  at org.eclipse.oomph.util.OomphPlugin.coreException(OomphPlugin.java:296)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.resolve(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:446)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.p2.internal.core.ProfileTransactionImpl.commit(ProfileTransactionImpl.java:356)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2.impl.P2TaskImpl.perform(P2TaskImpl.java:904)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3864)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:5200)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2448)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2473)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:5193)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3798)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.performTriggeredSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3773)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.perform(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3651)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$9.run(ProgressPage.java:592)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.ui.wizards.ProgressPage$11$1.run(ProgressPage.java:721)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Software being installed: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1712681946756
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Mylyn WikiText Help UI 3.0.42.202201072301 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui 3.0.42.202201072301)
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 Mylyn WikiText Help UI 4.2.0.v20240130-0811 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui 4.2.0.v20240130-0811)
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1712681946756
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.feature.feature.group 4.2.0.v20240302-0923
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: artificial_root 1.0.0.v1712681946756
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 0.0.0
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: Mylyn WikiText Editors 3.0.42.202201072301 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group 3.0.42.202201072301)
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui [3.0.42.202201072301,3.0.42.202201072301]
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: Mylyn WikiText 4.2.0.v20240302-0923 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.feature.feature.group 4.2.0.v20240302-0923)
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.help.ui [4.2.0.v20240130-0811,4.2.0.v20240130-0811]
  ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=1 Cannot satisfy dependency:
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 From: Mylyn WikiText 3.0.42.202201072301 (org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext_feature.feature.group 3.0.42.202201072301)
    ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director code=0 To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group [3.0.42.202201072301,3.0.42.202201072301]

Took 5 seconds.
There are failed tasks.
Press Back to choose different settings or Cancel to abort.

While installing updates in Eclipse encountered this issue. I was trying to install EGit.
Also I see Framework Warning:
eclipse.buildId=4.31.0.20240307-1200 java.version=22 java.vendor=Eclipse Adoptium BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_US Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product -clear Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.

